# Useeffect dependency list warning from custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm building a react app and I'm trying to simplify calling my backend api with a custom hook using axios. This hook keeps loading and error state so that I don't have to keep that state in every component making a request. It also exposes a callApi() function which makes the actual requests which then changes the state in the hook. Here is the code for the custom hook.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'

export default <DataType>() => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataType>()

  async function callApi(config: AxiosRequestConfig) {
    setLoading(true)
    setError('')
    try {
      const response = await axios.request<DataType>(config)
      setData(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) setError(error.response.data.msg)
      else if (error.request) setError('A network error occured')
      else setError('An error occured')
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return {
    data,
    loading,
    error,
    callApi
  }
}
```

I then try to use this callApi() method in a useEffect hook in a component where I want to make a request.

```
const { data: posts, loading, error, callApi } = useApi<Post[]>()

  useEffect(() => {
    callApi({
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/blog'
    })
  }, [])
```

This works as expected, but my the linter(set up with create-react-app) gives this warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'callApi'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>   If I either add callApi to the dependency array or remove the dependency array altogether, an infinite loop will be created, since callApi updates the state, and I only want to call the api on mount.

If I remove the dependency list or add callApi to the dependency list, the effect will be called all the time in a infinite loop, and I just want to call on mount.

How should this warning be fixed, and is there any risk involved with the code(after all, the linter complains for a reason)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const callApi = useCallback(async (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  setLoading(true)
  setError('')
  try {
    const response = await axios.request<DataType>(config)
    setData(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) setError(error.response.data.msg)
    else if (error.request) setError('A network error occured')
    else setError('An error occured')
  } finally {
    setLoading(false)
  }
}), [])
```

... and ...

```
useEffect(() => {
  callApi({
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/blog'
  })
}, [callApi])
```

The `callApi` never changes, so pass it to the `useEffect` will have the same behavior of `useEffect(..., [])`

Answer (score -1):

Your `useEffect` use the callApi function returned by your custom hooks.

Since a function can change as any props or state in a component, React warns you that, if it will ever change, the new function will never be called.

If you want to get rid of the warning you should just add the function to the second argument array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    callApi({
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/blog'
    })
  }, [ callApi ])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! The problem is that if I add callApi to the dependency list, the effect will run any time callApi changes, which I don't want since I only want to call the api once(on mount). The above code leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: Take a look at this React FAQ: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies, it may help you with your problem